# How does android retrieve data from a website?

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to android, I'm trying to build an android app that is a front for a web portal. For example, Airbnb. They have a website, but they also have an android app that, using it's own layout, will show listings from their website.

There are many websites that teach how to or even directly convert your website to android apps. However, this will result in an app that loads too slowly and is unresponsive due to CPU usage.

Could anyone share any tutorial/guide to learn how to do this myself?

Million thanks.

Comment: Hi, the concept is, you have to call a Web Service from your android to consume the data from website like AirBnb, and return the value in json format for example

Comment: Hi, Thanks you very much for your reply, to be honest, i'm new to android, infact i just learned the udacity basic android tutorial few days ago. Do you know any article/tutorial for this?

Comment: i just searched through google for keyword "web service android" it came out plenty of tutorial. thanks you very much for your help :)

Comment: Hi, see my posted answer dude :)

Comment: DouglasQ, if somebody has given you a correct answer in the section below (5 Answers below), choose it as an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually load data from a web server you're gonna need an API which usually delivers the proper data using `JSON` or `XML` format so that you can properly parse and display that data. Building this API is in it self a complete course on its own.

But connecting to and requesting data from the API is usually done using some networking libraries. These are some of the better know libraries for this purpose.

1. [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp): A complete library with a set of tools for handling network connections and HTTP requests.
2. [RetroFit](https://github.com/square/retrofit):Type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java by Square, Inc. which is built on top of OkHttp.
3. [Async-Http-Client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client):

> The Async Http Client library's purpose is to allow Java applications
> to easily execute HTTP requests and asynchronously process the HTTP
> responses. The library also supports the WebSocket Protocol. The Async
> HTTP Client library is simple to use.

There tons of other good libraries.

Comment: When you use Android's [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadUrl(java.lang.String)), no explicit use of  `HttpURLConnection` or `OkHttp` is needed. Do you happen to know *which* is being used for [WebView.loadUrl()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadUrl(java.lang.String)) ?

Answer (score 0):

you would have to write an API/Web service or use if already exits to fetch data from web server. Basically the concept is that, the website itself must be pulling data from some database, so write an API which would fetch the data from same API and return JSON data and consume the API from your android app.

If you know PHP refere to this for the help :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Answer (score 0):

its called webservices 
Through android you get data in form of ***json*** from a web server and then return in custom view as you want.
Follow this link hope it will help
[Step by Step Method to Access Webservice from Android](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr)

Answer (score 0):

You can write WebService, in programming it generally refers to a web page(ex. Airbnb), that can be called from your android application which can pass in data to it, or receive data from it.

WebService is basically like a 'method' or 'function' in a normal programming language; except you're calling it over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you have to create a **Web Service**. The **Web Service** will be your "*bridge*" to consume the data from other Website like airbnb or others and return the data to your android through json format for example.

You can create a Web Service using many languages like C#, Java, PHP, etc. I would like to recommend you to use the language that you know the most.

You can try to google [this](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=7wDqV9CSJYH3vgT2w7KgDw#q=create%20web%20service%20for%20android)

Cheers